# Glassfish and java:comp/BeanManager

Tags: glassfish, java-ee-6, cdi

I have .war application that I deploy to glassfish. I want to do CDI, so I need to lookup java:comp/BeanManager from my POJO. But it does not work: BeanManager simply not found!

What is wrong?

Do I need to enable CDI in glassfish? Or it works only in .ear files?

thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Do you have an empty beans.xml under WEB-INF folder? Without beans.xml, CDI is not enabled.

Comment: @Ilya K: if this answer solved your problem, please be sure to accept it. :)